# Need to use grep to find a string within a file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

Im using a shell script to get a file using wget and search it for a pattern. My shell script is as follows:

```
#Execute commands one by one
while read line
do
        STARTTIME=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
        line2=$(wget -q --post-data "$line" -O PHPFiles/test.php http://localhost:1234/XSS/XSS2/test.php)
        ENDTIME=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
        GAP=$(($ENDTIME-$STARTTIME))
        DIFF=$(($DIFF+($ENDTIME-$STARTTIME)))
        echo "Time Taken "$GAP

        finalSearchLine1="${line/&name2=/ }"
        finalSearchLine2="${finalSearchLine1/name=/}"

        echo "$finalSearchLine2"

        if grep -q -F "$finalSeachLine2" -a PHPFiles/test.php;
        then
                echo found
                success=$((success+1))
        else
                echo not found
                failure=$((failure+1))
        fi
        rm PHPFiles/test.php
done < $1
echo "***************"
echo "Success "$success
echo "Failure "$failure
echo "Total Time "$DIFF
echo "Average Time "$((DIFF/(success+failure)))
```

However, I'm having trouble with the grep command. Sometimes, the data `$finalSearchLine2` contains quotes such as:

```
<script >alert("XSS"); </script>
```

This seem to cause trouble with the grep command. For the `if` statement, I always seem to get the result as `found` even when there is no matching pattern in the `$finalSearchLine2` variable. I dont know if its possible to use escape strings within the variable for grep. Can anyone suggest a possible solution for this?

Comment: The quotes in the search string are not a problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Grep needs double quotes to be escaped like this `\"`
So as a first solution you could try:

```
temp_variable=$(sed 's/"/\\"/g' <<< $temp)
if  grep -q -F "$temp_variable" -a /PHPFiles/test.php;
```

So you first escape the double quotes with sed and you store the result in temp_variable. Then you use temp_variable in grep.